# Load PNG into Bitmap without pixel modification

Tags: java, android, image, compression

I'm trying to load a PNG into a Bitmap object using BitmapFactory like this:

`BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.tile_18_23);`

The raw values of the pixels will be used in a GL shader program and need to be exact (or at least as close as floats every get) but what I'm getting is clipped for low values (anything lower than RGB 20 or so is translated to zero for any color channel) and some sort of color-space mapping appears to be happening that I haven't been able to reason about.  The values are off by 2x or more.

I've tried tons of configurations of `BitmapFactory.Options` but none of them seem to produce output consistent with raw input. In worst-case I'd be ok with re-mapping the colors but can't figure out the logic it's using and neither `options.inPreferredColorSpace` or `options.outColorSpace` appear to have much impact.  Based on other answers, here's my best attempt at options that still doesn't work:

```
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inDither = false;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.tile_18_23, options);
```

Tried putting the image in both assets and drawable-nodpi without any change.

If I read the PNG using Golang, all the channels have exactly the values I'd expect in the PNG so I don't think the problem is in creation of the PNG.

Comment: For this, I'd definitely go `assets/` over a resource. You might try unpacking your APK (it's a ZIP file), grabbing the PNG out of there, and try that with your Golang code (or maybe just compare hashes with a known-good PNG). If the APK copy is different, then the issue may be that your PNG is being modified as part of the build process. Another way to do the same test is to try reading in a PNG that is stored as a file on the device.